# SQL Join statement failing on where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

PROBLEM SOLVED. Turns out some other section of the PHP code was screwing with what I was doing. D'Oh

Thanks everyone for your quick responses though.

===

Can anyone illuminate what could be going wrong here:

```
SELECT * FROM sale_item 
JOIN sale 
ON sale_item.id_sale = sale.id 
WHERE sale.id_job = 1 AND sale_item.id_product = 1
```

I'm getting an error from MySQL: "`Unknown column 'id_product' in 'where clause`' "

It's very frustrating as this should be pretty simple. But I'm kind of new to SQL. So have I missed anything syntax-wise that could be causing this problem? Both tables and all columns exist.

EDIT - update

It turs out it's not the join. I can't get it to recognize the id_product field exists, even though I can browse that table and the data within it using phpmyadmin.

Here is the export of the sale_item table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sale_item` (
`id_sale` int(11) default NULL,
`id_product` int(11) default NULL,
`amount` int(11) default '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now, I cut it back and even this still isn't working:

```
SELECT * FROM sale_item WHERE id_product = 1
```

Comment: Do you have id_product column in sale_item Table?

Comment: Please show output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE sale_item`.

Comment: "Can anyone illuminate what could be going wrong here" - you forgot to read the error message.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the `SELECT` on the *same* server & database as that `SHOW` statement?

Comment: seems to be your table sale_item  doesn't contains a column named id_product

Comment: @Cipheron: Please could you explain what was going on more fully (perhaps post an answer to your own question) so that this question might be of some help to others in the future?

Comment: Just comment this `AND sale_item.id_product = 1` and see whether you get results from the rest of the query.

Comment: Downvoting as question is "not useful" so long as the problem is not explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax looks OK. The error message strongly suggests that the table `sale_item` had no column named `id_product`. Maybe it is in the `sale` table?

You should add a list of all the columns of each table to your question.

Comment: -1 The `sale_item` table does contain an `id_product` column.

Comment: turns out it was another section of code causing the problems, not the bit I was working on. oldest story in the book

Comment: @eggyal After the questioner took my advice and added more information to his question that became obvious, yes. As you could have noticed, I posted way before the update.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you jumped to an incorrect conclusion and posted that as an answer, rather than requesting more information by way of comment ([as I did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573969/sql-join-statement-failing-on-where-clause#comment32587453_21573969))?  In my book, that's an answer that deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

> Your table, whose name is stored in sale_item, does not have a column
>   named id_product . This makes the query fail.

Please make sure that your column name is correct